# ng-route with id is working but id with id from json is wrong

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

This is main.html structure

```
<ul ng-repeat = 'user in users'>    
 <li>{{user.first_name}} <span>X</span></li>
 <li>{{user.last_name}}</li>
 <li>{{user.email}}</li>
 <a href="#footer/{{user.id}}"/><li>{{user.id}}</li></a>
 </ul>
```

This is my route.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/footer/:id",{
templateUrl:'./footer.html',
controller: "getCtrl"
})
.when("/nemke",{
templateUrl:"./form.html"
})
.otherwise({
redirectTo:"/"  
})
});
app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name = "nemkesafsafa";

});
```

This is main.js file

```
var app = angular.module("app",['ngRoute']);
app.controller('getCtrl',['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'users', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, users) {
users.success(function(data){
var obje = data[0].first_name;
console.log(obje);
var keys  =  [];
$scope.profile = data[$routeParams.id];

for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
    keys.push(data[i].id);
}
$scope.users  = data;
});
users.error(function(){
    console.log("Nemke")
})
}]);
```

json.php

```
[{"id":"126","first_name":"Nemanja","last_name":"Dukic","email":"Car"},{"id":"127","first_name":"Nemanja","last_name":"Dukic","email":"Car"}]
```

footer.html

```
<div>
<h2>{{profile.id}}</h2>
<h2>{{profile.fist_name}}</h2>
<h2>{{profile.last_name}}</h2>
<h2>{{profile.email}}</h2>

</div>
```

So the problem is when i clikc on link the url is fine, but the data dipslay id footer.html is wrong

Here's the picuter it's easire this way

See discription in below image.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your footer.html moreover looks like $scope.profile = data[$routeParams.id]; you are assiging the index based element shouldn't it be filterted for id ?

Comment: where is footer.html

Comment: Sorry updated answer the footer @VinodLouis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.profile = data[$routeParams.id];

should be replaced

```
 $scope.profile = data.find(function(ele){
    return ele.id == $routeParams.id
 });
```